# The real projective space $\mathbb{R}P^{n}$ is second countable.

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

. The real projective space $\mathbb{R}P^{n}$ is second countable.

How to prove this. I have to use this proof in a solution of a question. But I cannot prove. Please help me. Write the proof clearly.

Comment: Already $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ is second countable, and its quotient is $\Bbb RP^n$.

Comment: Oww ok. Can you give an answer More clearly instead of a Hint. Because i do a project. But I am confused so much. I need to write the proof clearly. Please more explain. This is a so small part of my project. Thank you @berci

Comment: Just for pedantry's sake, $\mathbb RP^n$ is not a quotient space of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, it is a quotient space of the subspace $\mathbb R^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$. @Berci

Comment: Ah, yes, indeed. I wanted to mean so.

Comment: What? I cannot understand. Please write more clear. I am a new learner to manifold.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews please can you write more clearly expilicit answer. Please. I am new learner. I cannot understand anything you said at comment.

Comment: @B11 I was commenting on Berci's note, not answering the question.

Comment: @B11, we are not here to do your homework, we can give you hints so that you find the solution yourself but that's it.

Comment: This is not homework. I want to learn this proof. I am a new learner. So I cannot produce any idea about it. Please teach me. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: If you are self-learning, all the more reason not to hand you the answer. What do you know about second-countability? What do you know about $\mathbb RP^n$?

Comment: If this was a homework, I would find via google. @DimitriSurinx ın order to learn, I ask here.

Comment: @B11, the best way to learn is to give it a shot yourself! The hints supplied already should be enough if you know your definitions and theorems in topology.

Comment: I dont know topology. I have learn for a week

Comment: Given your tone and what you've written, I doubt you will find many people here who will believe your claim that this is not homework.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$\Bbb R^{n+1}$ has a countable base (namely open balls of rational radii on rational points).

Assume that $X$ has a countable base $\mathcal U$.

1. Then any of its subsets $Y\subseteq X$ has a countable base (namely $\{U\cap Y\,\mid\,U\in\mathcal U\}$).
2. If $Z=X/{\sim}$ is a quotient of $X$ by an equivalence relation $\sim$, then $\{\{[x]_\sim\,\mid\, x\in U\}\ \mid\, U\in\mathcal U\}$ will be a countable base for the induced topology of $Z$.

Now, apply 1. for $X=\Bbb R^{n+1}$ and $Y=\Bbb R^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$, then apply 2. for $X=\Bbb R^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ and $a\sim b \iff (a=\lambda b$ for some $\lambda\in\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Ohh you are so good teacher @berci. I want to learn, bu nobody want to explain. Giving hints does not imagine in my mind. Thank you so much. I Try to understand Now. If there is problem, I ask. Thank you

Comment: I understand the topic by myself. But I cannot apply some thm's in the questions or proofs. So need ro teach someone. Thus I ask here.

Comment: @B11, then you do not understand the topic, it's through exercise  that one learns a subject.

Comment: @Berci, regarding 2. one should also prove that the equivalence classes are open, right?

Comment: @Ram, I believe the equivalence relation must be open... that is, the projection has to be an open map.

Comment: Could you give a hint on showing claim 2.?

Comment: Let $\pi:X\to X/\sim\ x\mapsto[x] _\sim$. Then $V\subseteq X/\sim$ is open by definition iff $U:=\pi^{-1}(V)\subseteq X$ is open. Now $U$ can be written as the union of base sets, and $V=\pi(U)$.

Answer (score 10):

Use the follow proposition: The image of a continuous open map on a second-countable space is second countable.

Consider $\mathbb RP^n$ as $S^n$ with antipodal points identified. $S^n$ is second-countable as a subspace of a second-countable space. All that is left to prove is that the quotient map $\pi:S^n -> \mathbb RP^n$ is a open map, because it is continuous by definition.

The quotient map $\pi$ is a open map when for every open $V$ in the n-sphere, $\pi^{-1}(\pi(V))$ is also open in the n-sphere .

Comment: I'm glad I could help and leave the 'tricky' part as a exercise.

Answer (score 2):

You can show first $\mathbb{R}^n$ is 2nd countable, then show $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is 2nd countable, see: e.g. http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~idarcy/COURSES/133/3_2rpns.pdf